# two for loops, the inner for loop increase 1000 times, while the speed only increase 100 times?

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory

I am in the process of analyze the computation complexity of the algorithm, I have two for loops.

```
    short i=0;
    short j=0;
    short ii=0;
    short[] counts = new short[2];

    int label_size  = MapRedUtils.label_size;
    int max_index=0;                        
    int sample_size =data.getSampleSize();

    float max_ig = 0;
    float totalVar=0;
    float var=0;
    float cov_ig;

    float[] tocopy = new float[label_size];        
    float[][] sums = new float[2][];
    float[] totalSum = new float[label_size];



    byte value;
    ByteBuffer label = ByteBuffer.allocate(label_size*4); 

    for( j=0; j<2; j++ )        
        sums[j] = new float[label_size];

    for( ii=0; ii<3; ii++)// 3 ways of split the current node
    {          
          long startTime;
    long endTime;
    long totalTime;
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        counts[0]=0;
        counts[1]=0;

        System.arraycopy(tocopy,0,totalSum,0,label_size);
        System.arraycopy(tocopy,0,sums[0],0,label_size);
        System.arraycopy(tocopy,0,sums[1],0,label_size);

        for ( i = 0; i < sample_size; i++) 
        {
            OneSample instance = data.get(i);
            value = (byte) instance.getTheGenoytpe(snpid);

            label = instance.getPhenotype();                                                                          

            if( value==ii)
            {   
                counts[0]++;
                for(j=0; j< label_size; j++)
                     sums[0][j] += label.getFloat(j*4);
            }
            else
            {
                counts[1]++;                    
                for(j=0; j< label_size; j++)
                    sums[1][j] += label.getFloat(j*4);                    
            }

            for(j=0; j< label_size; j++)  
                totalSum[j] += label.getFloat(j*4);
        }                                              

          totalVar=0;
          var=0;
         for(i=0; i< label_size; i++)
         {
           totalVar += totalSum[i]*totalSum[i];          
         } 

        totalVar = totalVar/sample_size;//it is averaged by sample size

        for(j=0; j< 2; j++)
           //var += sumSquared(sums[j],  MapRedUtils.inverse_covariance , counts[j]);  
             var += sumSquared(sums[j], counts[j]);


        cov_ig = var- totalVar;

        if(cov_ig > max_ig)
        {
            max_ig=cov_ig;
            max_index=ii;
        } 
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();                    
        totalTime = (endTime - startTime);
        System.out.println(totalTime);
```

I increase the inner label_size  from label_size=1 and label_size=1000, I expect the running time should increase 1000 times, while actually the running time increase only 40-100 times for different runs.
 Why is like this?

Comment: What language? (That sample pseudo-code doesn't have nested loops in the languages I know.)

Comment: In theory, theory and practice are the same. Could you please show some *real* code?

Comment: I use java thanks I am showing the real code now

Comment: A profiler would be of value here, so you could see where the time is being consumed.

Comment: Ever heard of [SSCCE.org](http://SSCCE.org)?

Answer (score 1):

When label = 1, most of the time of the outer loop is taken in "do something here" and setting up the inner loop because running only once through the loop "do something here also" is only a small percentage of the work. Assume "do something here" and setting up the inner loop takes 100 units of time and "do something here also" takes only 10 units of time. The total running time of the program would be 110 * sample_size.  Now you increase label to 1000.  100 + 10 * 1000 = 10100. So the total running time is 10100 * sample_size. 10100 / 110 = 91.8. Because "Do something here" took some time, it significantly reduced the impact of increasing label. You have to consider the ratio of "Do something here" to "do something here also", not just the ratio of old label value to new label value.